# Selenium test work with mstest but not vstest.console

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mstest

I am able to run these tests in MSTest. But I am now wanting to gain more control and utilizing runsettings files/parameters etc. I have upgraded the packages to point to `mstest.adapter`, `mstest.testframework`.

I am getting the error

```
'Warning: No test is available in .\xxxxx.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.'
```

All the fixes refer to NUNIT, which I am not utilizing.

Here are the packages that I am using:

```
      <package id="DnsClient" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" version="3.11.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="ExtentReports" version="4.0.3" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Microsoft.CodeCoverage" version="16.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" version="16.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Microsoft.UnitTestFramework.Extensions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform" version="14.0.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.7.2" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.7.2" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.7.2" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="RazorEngine" version="3.10.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="System.Diagnostics.Contracts" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Thanks Kate for trying to help. I executed the log and this is what I got. I don't see any stand out error,do you see anything that stands out?

```
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.574, 189095880569, vstest.console.exe, Program: Starting the runner.
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.589, 189096017091, vstest.console.exe, CommonUtilities.ResolveFilePath: File path resolved to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.dll
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.751, 189097630015, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginCache: Creating the plugin discoverer.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.751, 189097633739, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginCache: Discovering the extensions using extension path.
E, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.770, 189097823402, vstest.console.exe, TryGetTestExtensionFromType: Discovered multiple test extensions with identifier data 'MSAppContainerTest'; keeping the first one.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.864, 189098767154, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginCache: Discovered the extensions using extension path ''.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.865, 189098774569, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginCache: Discoverers are 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.GenericTestAdapter.GenericTestDiscoverer, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.GenericTestAdapter, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter.MSAppContainerTestDiscoverer, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter.MSPhoneTestDiscoverer, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSPhoneAdapter, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.OrderedTestAdapter.OrderedTestDiscoverer, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.OrderedTestAdapter, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.MSTestDiscoverer, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppUnitTestExtension.TestDiscoverer, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppPhoneUnitTestExtension, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppUnitTestExtension.TestDiscoverer, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppUnitTestExtension, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.865, 189098774888, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginCache: Executors are 'executor://GenericTestAdapter/v1,executor://MSAppContainerTestAdapter/v1,executor://uapexecutoridentifier/,executor://MSWPTestAdapter/v1,executor://OrderedTestAdapter/v1,executor://MSTestAdapter/v1,executor://CppWPUnitTestExecutor/v1,executor://CppUnitTestExecutor/v1,executor://UAPCppExecutorIdentifier'.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.865, 189098775052, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginCache: Setting providers are 'DataCollectionRunSettings,RunConfiguration,MSAppContainerTest,MSTest'.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.865, 189098775299, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginCache: Loggers are 'logger://Microsoft/TestPlatform/ConsoleLogger/v1,logger://Microsoft/TestPlatform/TfsLogger/v1,logger://Microsoft/TeamFoundation/TimelineLogger,logger://Microsoft/TestPlatform/TrxLogger/v1'.
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.872, 189098843850, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginManager.CreateTestExtension: Attempting to load test extension: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.ConsoleLogger
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.876, 189098882221, vstest.console.exe, ConfigurationHelper: Using UseVsixExtensions with value False.
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.883, 189098952747, vstest.console.exe, RunTestsArgumentProcessor:Execute: Test run is starting.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.917, 189099297625, vstest.console.exe, Inferred Multi-Targeting settings:.\Cit.Found.AutomatedTesting.dll Platform:AnyCPU FrameworkVersion:Framework45
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.922, 189099341536, vstest.console.exe, Using effective platform:X86 effective framework:Framework45
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.939, 189099516944, vstest.console.exe, Using platformType InProc for inIsolation=False.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.947, 189099597731, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync: Creating test run request.
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.949, 189099618704, vstest.console.exe, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.Internal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a: Resolving assembly.
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.952, 189099647525, vstest.console.exe, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.Internal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a: Resolved assembly. 
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.954, 189099663489, vstest.console.exe, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry, Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a: Resolving assembly.
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:02.956, 189099685850, vstest.console.exe, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry, Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a: Resolved assembly. 
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.008, 189100200359, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync: Created test run request.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.010, 189100224522, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync: Starting.
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.011, 189100233400, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync: Starting run with settings:TestRunCriteria:
   KeepAlive=False,FrequencyOfRunStatsChangeEvent=10,RunStatsChangeEventTimeout=00:00:01.5000000,TestCaseFilter=,TestExecutorLauncher=
   Settingsxml=<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>E:\development\cit\Cit.Found.AutomatedTesting\code\bin\debug\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
    <TargetPlatform>X86</TargetPlatform>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework45</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>

V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.011, 189100234083, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync: Wait for the first run request is over.
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.016, 189100279482, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginManager.CreateTestExtension: Attempting to load test extension: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.RunConfigurationSettingsProvider
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.018, 189100305267, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync: Started.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.018, 189100305476, vstest.console.exe, RunTestsArgumentProcessor:Execute: Test run is queued.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.019, 189100309292, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest.WaitForCompletion: Waiting with timeout -1.
I, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.033, 189100451215, vstest.console.exe, TestDiscoveryManager: Discovering tests from sources .\Cit.Found.AutomatedTesting.dll
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.038, 189100508009, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutionManager.RunTests: Running tests for executor://MSAppContainerTestAdapter/v1
I, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.038, 189100508904, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginManager.CreateTestExtension: Attempting to load test extension: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter.MSAppContainerTestExecutor
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.053, 189100657694, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutionManager.RunTests: Completed running tests for executor://MSAppContainerTestAdapter/v1
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.053, 189100658060, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutionManager.RunTests: Running tests for executor://MSWPTestAdapter/v1
I, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.053, 189100658837, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginManager.CreateTestExtension: Attempting to load test extension: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter.MSPhoneTestExecutor
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.062, 189100739590, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutionManager.RunTests: Completed running tests for executor://MSWPTestAdapter/v1
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.062, 189100739930, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutionManager.RunTests: Running tests for executor://MSTestAdapter/v1
I, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.062, 189100740505, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginManager.CreateTestExtension: Attempting to load test extension: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.MSTestExecutor
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.066, 189100779723, vstest.console.exe, MixedModeExecutor: Started doing deployment for source .\Cit.Found.AutomatedTesting.dll.
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.071, 189100835532, vstest.console.exe, Removing source .\Cit.Found.AutomatedTesting.dll from the source list as it does not contain any test.
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.071, 189100835889, vstest.console.exe, MixedModeExecutor: Deployment done for all the sources .\Cit.Found.AutomatedTesting.dll.
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.071, 189100837391, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutionManager.RunTests: Completed running tests for executor://MSTestAdapter/v1
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.071, 189100837564, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutionManager.RunTests: Running tests for executor://CppWPUnitTestExecutor/v1
I, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.072, 189100838375, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginManager.CreateTestExtension: Attempting to load test extension: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppUnitTestExtension.TestExecutor
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.084, 189100960512, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutionManager.RunTests: Completed running tests for executor://CppWPUnitTestExecutor/v1
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.084, 189100960770, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutionManager.RunTests: Running tests for executor://CppUnitTestExecutor/v1
I, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.084, 189100961375, vstest.console.exe, TestPluginManager.CreateTestExtension: Attempting to load test extension: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppUnitTestExtension.TestExecutor
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.087, 189100994462, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutionManager.RunTests: Completed running tests for executor://CppUnitTestExecutor/v1
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.094, 189101059506, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest:SendTestRunMessage: Starting.
I, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.095, 189101072139, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest:SendTestRunMessage: Completed.
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.098, 189101099486, vstest.console.exe, RocksteadyTestRunEventReceiver:TestRunComplete: No results are available in last chunk.
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.099, 189101111570, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest:TestRunComplete: Starting. IsAborted:False IsCanceled:False.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.104, 189101162891, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest.Dispose: Starting.
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.143, 189101549590, vstest.console.exe, TelemetrySession: Sending the telemetry data to the server.
I, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.144, 189101563703, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest:TestRunComplete: Completed.
V, 10968, 10, 2019/03/26, 13:44:03.144, 189101564110, vstest.console.exe, TestExecutionManager.RunTests: Run is complete.
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:04.696, 189117079086, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest.Dispose: Completed.
I, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:04.706, 189117182252, vstest.console.exe, RunTestsArgumentProcessor:Execute: Test run is completed.
V, 10968, 1, 2019/03/26, 13:44:04.722, 189117343835, vstest.console.exe, Executor.Execute: Exiting with exit code of 0
```

Comment: You may find this bug report helpful: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1303

Comment: I looked Kate, and I don't see anything that stands out. Do you see anything?

Comment: Are you required to use .net core instead of .net framework? The reason I ask is because there are nuget packages that I need that won't work in .netcore, but I want to be able to use runsettings to control aspects of the tests.